# Is it possible to calculate the sum of each month within a loop?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, date

I want to find the sum of each month using a loop, but am struggling to find a code that differentiates months with 30 days and months with 31 days?

My current code is below can anybody help me?

```
`Sub MonthlyPeak()

Dim Peak As Range, p As Double, i As Integer, r  As Integer
For r = 4 To 26404 **Step 672**
For i = 9 To 231
    Set Peak = Worksheets("coa_20150409").Range(Cells(r, i), Cells(r + 671, i))
    p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Peak)
    Worksheets("MonthlyPeak").Cells(r, i).Value = p
Next i
Next r
End Sub`
```

The Step by 672 refers to hourly data calculated for the month assuming 24 hr 7 days, however this does not account for the differential in days of each month.

Comment: Not sure if this could help you https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

Comment: Is there a column in your data that contains the **date** and **time** ??

Comment: I have a column with the date and time in column A and then my data in Column I to HP

Comment: VBA has a `Month()` function which will return the month number for a date.    If the dates are sorted, you could use a `Do: go to next row...While: Month(date) = Month(previous row)` loop to find the break point for a month.  As a side note, you code is using `Max` but you are talking about a sum.